# how to correctly render controller output to GSP

Tags: grails, view, controller, gsp

in my grails application, I have a controller that reads a directory and returns a list of files in it.

My issue is that in my GSP (view) it is not matching the out put from the controller.

Here is my controller:

```
package frametest

import groovy.io.FileType

class Read_dirController {

    def index() { 

        def list = []

        def dir = new File("D:\\TestRepoLocal\\APIAutomation\\src\\test\\cucumber\\features")
        dir.eachFileRecurse (FileType.FILES) { file ->
          list << file
        }

        list.each {
            println it.name
          }

        def found = []
        dir.eachFileMatch(FileType.ANY, ~/.feature/) {
            found << it.name
        }

        render(view: "index",  model: [name:name])      
    }

}
```

here is my GSP (view):

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"/>
<meta name="layout" content="main"/>
<title>Welcome to The Marriot test Page</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="body">
    <h2>Marriott Automation Test Page</h2>
    <br>
    <p></p>
    <h3>This is where we can launch our tests and get reports</h3>
    <br>
    <br>
    <p></p>

    ${name}

  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The output should just list the file names. It does in the controller output (shown in console), but in the view it shows this:

```
[D:\TestRepoLocal\APIAutomation\src\test\cucumber\features\APIWAL_525_Account_Security_otp.feature, D:\TestRepoLocal\APIAutomation\src\test\cucumber\features\AssignRoomToReservation.feature, D:\TestRepoLocal\APIAutomation\src\test\cucumber\features\DeleteAccount.feature, D:\TestRepoLocal\APIAutomation\src\test\cucumber\features\DeleteConsumersPaymentMethods.feature, D:\TestRepoLocal\APIAutomation\src\test\cucumber\features\GetActivitiesByID.feature, D:\TestRepoLocal\APIAutomation\src\test\cucumber\features\GetAddressType.feature, D:\TestRepoLocal\APIAutomation\src\test\cucumber\features\GetAddrMiscType.feature, D:\TestRepo
```

Local\APIAutomation\src\test\cucumber\features\GetAlerts.feature,

the console output for the controller shows this:

```
APIWAL_525_Account_Security_otp.feature
AssignRoomToReservation.feature
DeleteAccount.feature
DeleteConsumersPaymentMethods.feature
GetActivitiesByID.feature
GetAddressType.feature
GetAddrMiscType.feature
GetAlerts.feature
GetAttractionsByID.feature
```

What do i need to do to make the view match the controller output from console??

thanks!

ironmantis7x

UPDATE!!!!!

to solve my listing issue I did this:
I changed the controller file to do this little trick:

```
render(view: "index",  model: [name:list.name])
```

then to make the gsp list the file names on a new line, I did this:

```
<ul>
        <g:each in="${name}" var="fileName">
               ${fileName}<br>
        </g:each>
    </ul>
```

And presto!!

```
This is where we can launch our tests and get reports



APIWAL_525_Account_Security_otp.feature




 AssignRoomToReservation.feature
 DeleteAccount.feature
 DeleteConsumersPaymentMethods.feature
 GetActivitiesByID.feature
 GetAddressType.feature
 GetAddrMiscType.feature
```

.....

Thanks guys for encouraging me to struggle to learn it and helping me along the way!

Comment: Try getting rid of println line. When you use println in your controller, sometimes the list doesn't show in view.

Comment: @monty_bean: I tried that and that did not work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your gsp is rendering the list but your list of names is in the variable found, not name. Anyway, your last action line should be:

```
render(view: "index",  model: [name: found])
```

In other hand, your gsp is rendering the list, but should give it some style. An example:

```
<ul>
    <g:each in="${name}" var="fileName">
           <li>${fileName}</li>
    </g:each>
</ul>
```

Comment: the view (gsp) is blank.Console still shows the file list, but with the code you posted, gsp is blank...

Comment: Change the controller as I said then.

Comment: I changed the controller to show the list, and it "works". However it is showing the full directory path and the filename instead of the filename

Comment: @ironmantis7x are you using the found or the list variable into the model map? As I see, found should be an array of Strings, with all file names.

Comment: when i switched it to found I get a list of the file names with the entire directory path as well. I just want the file names. Sorry I am new to Grails.

Comment: When you print an object, grails call to its toString() method. So if you have a list of File Objects, you will receive a list their fullpath name string. So maybe you are not creating the list correctly, but I can not see that in your code, because you are doing a left shift with it.name. Debugging the code it's the best way to see what is happening.

Comment: This seems to be the most correct solution. It gets me basically what I need. I still have to strip off the file path from the name, but that is another issue I need to tackle and learn.
Thanks guys!!

Answer (score 1):

You are storing your o/p in field named `found`, but in model you are using field `name` to be included as name, which doesn't contain your o/p. You haven't declared name, or have added anything to it, idk how it is showing that o/p even on gsp.